# fpdf printing cell table vertically

Tags: cell, fpdf

I have this data from mysql database:

[image]
[image]

Using this code:

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require("aacfs.php");

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
$locquery=mysql_query("select * from ptr where reservno = '0000187' group by ptr_id asc") or die(mysql_error());

while($locrow=mysql_fetch_array($locquery))
{
    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $locrow['location'], 1, 0, 'C');
}
$pdf->Ln();
$fquoquery=mysql_query("select distinct fquo_id as 'fquo_id' from passengers where reservno = '0000187' group by pass_id asc") or die(mysql_error());
while($fquorow=mysql_fetch_array($fquoquery))
{
    $fquo=$fquorow['fquo_id'];
    $passquery=mysql_query("select * from passengers where fquo_id = '$fquo' group by pass_id asc") or die(mysql_error());
    while($passrow=mysql_fetch_array($passquery))
    {
        $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $passrow['pass_name'], 1, 0, 'C');
    }
    $pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I'm trying to generate a pdf with this output:

[image]

But I'm having this wrong output instead:

[image]

How can I achieve the desired output using fpdf? Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

The best example i could give you on how to achieve this would be to adjust the following query and variables to meet your needs:

```
<?php


require('fpdf.php');

//Connect to your database
include("conectmysql.php");

//Create new pdf file
$pdf=new FPDF();

//Disable automatic page break
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);

//Add first page
$pdf->AddPage();

//set initial y axis position per page
$y_axis_initial = 25;

//print column titles
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'CODE',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(100,6,'NAME',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'PRICE',1,0,'R',1);

$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

//Select the Products you want to show in your PDF file
$result=mysql_query('select Code,Name,Price from Products ORDER BY Code',$link);

//initialize counter
$i = 0;

//Set maximum rows per page
$max = 25;

//Set Row Height
$row_height = 6;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
//If the current row is the last one, create new page and print column title
if ($i == $max)
{
    $pdf->AddPage();

    //print column titles for the current page
    $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
    $pdf->SetX(25);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'CODE',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(100,6,'NAME',1,0,'L',1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,'PRICE',1,0,'R',1);

    //Go to next row
    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

    //Set $i variable to 0 (first row)
    $i = 0;
}

$code = $row['Code'];
$price = $row['Price'];
$name = $row['Code'];

$pdf->SetY($y_axis);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,$code,1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(100,6,$name,1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,$price,1,0,'R',1);

//Go to next row
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
$i = $i + 1;
}

mysql_close($link);

//Send file
$pdf->Output();
?>
```